# In Visual Studio 2015+, how do I determine what object caused a null exception?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, silverlight

Thanks for looking. I am debugging a Silverlight project and and it is throwing a null exception that is reported to the DOM. Unfortunately, I have no idea where in the codebase that the exception is being thrown.

I can catch the exception in the class file to view more details about it, but it still isn't clear where about what value is null or where it is.

How do I determine the object and location of the object that is causing the null exception?

Here is the error message that Silverlight returns to the DOM for those that are interested:

> Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application  Code: 4004
>   Category: ManagedRuntimeError        Message:
>   System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   source    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncServices.b__0(Object
>   state)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to turn on the setting that Visual Studio will break when `NullReferenceException` is thrown and not only when it's unhandled.

To do that, go to `Debug->Windows->Exception settings` window, filter for `NullReferenceException` and tick the checkbox for in the `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` section.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @pawellukasik!